# Android MediaCodec WebM transparency supporting

Tags: android, opengl-es, video-processing, android-mediacodec, webm

I couldn't find any documentation about supporting android transparency in WebM.

I tested a lot of WebM videos on different android devices and looks like transparency supported only by chrome video player in browser.

If anybody knows the way how to decode video in WebM format with transparent background by Android MediaCodec, please share your knowledge.